# Remove logo and footer for letterhead printing then re-insert

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to remove parts of a document so that it can print on letterhead on the first page, and once printed re-insert the logo and footer.

I have created bookmarks to select the exact area, and then replace that selection with an Autotext which is blank, then once printed select the area again and insert another Autotext with the logo. When I do this manually, the process works. When I record this and try to run it the macro immediately says it can't find the Bookmark.

I know that this is going to be because the bookmarks are defined in the template rather than the document, but I don't know enough VBA to properly declare where to find the bookmark.

I have recorded four Macros.

Macro1 goes to the logo bookmark and selects the range, then inserts the blanking autotext.

```
Sub Macro1()
    '
    ' Macro1 Macro
    '
    '
    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, name:="HeaderLogo"
        With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
        .DefaultSorting = wdSortByName
        .ShowHidden = True
    End With

    Application.Templates( _
        "C:\Users\Mick\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Word\STARTUP\DocumentManager.dotm" _
         ).BuildingBlockEntries("HearderLogoBlankAuto").Insert Where:=Selection. _
        Range, RichText:=True
End Sub
```

Macro2 goes to the same Logo bookmark to select the range again and now inserts the logo

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'
'
    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, name:="HeaderLogo"
    With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
        .DefaultSorting = wdSortByName
        .ShowHidden = True
    End With
    Application.Templates( _
        "C:\Users\Nathan\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Word\STARTUP\DocumentManager.dotm" _
        ).BuildingBlockEntries("HeaderLogoAuto").Insert Where:=Selection. _
        Range, RichText:=True
End Sub
```

The last two macros do the same thing for the footer.

Comment: You could email me the word documents and VBA code and I will take a look at it

Comment: It'd be easier to have the macro just make a copy of the document, take out the parts you don't want, print it, and then discard the document.